# Unable to make an expandable v-data-table in vuetify3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I am trying to make an expandable v-data-table in vue3 and vuetify3. The normal data table worked fine. However when I am trying an expandable v-data-table. It does not display anything but loads data as appears from the pagination.

Updated code: All of the rows expand together now

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import currencyHelpers from '../lib/currencyHelpers';

const info = ref([]);
const currencies = ref([]);
const headers = [
  { title: 'Name', value: 'currencydefinition.fullyqualifiedname' },
  { title: 'ID', value: 'currencydefinition.currencyid' },
  { title: 'ID rego fee', value: 'currencydefinition.idregistrationfees' },
  { title: 'ID import fee', value: 'currencydefinition.idimportfees' },
  { title: 'Converter Name', value: 'currencydefinition.gatewayconvertername' },
  { title: 'Proof Protocol', value: 'currencydefinition.proofprotocol' },
  { title: 'Options', value: 'currencydefinition.options' }
];
const expanded = ref(null);

(async () => {
  info.value = await currencyHelpers.getInfo();
  currencies.value = await currencyHelpers.listCurrencies();
})();

</script>

<template>
  <v-layout>
    <v-row>
      <v-col>
    <h1>Currencies</h1>
    <v-container class="mx-auto pa-6">
      <v-data-table 
      :items="currencies" 
      :headers="headers" 
      item-value="title"
      v-model:expanded="expanded"
      show-expand
    >
      <!-- expanded card content -->
      <template v-slot:top>
        <v-toolbar flat>
          <v-toolbar-title>Version {{ info.VRSCversion }}</v-toolbar-title>
        </v-toolbar>
      </template>

        <template v-slot:expanded-row="items">
          <tr>
            <td :colspan="headers.length">
              More info about {{ headers }}
            </td>
          </tr>
        </template>
    </v-data-table>

    </v-container>
    </v-col>
    </v-row>
    </v-layout>

</template>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

This is the JSON response btw:

```
More info about [ { "title": "Name", "value": "currencydefinition.fullyqualifiedname" }, { "title": "ID", "value": "currencydefinition.currencyid" }, { "title": "ID rego fee", "value": "currencydefinition.idregistrationfees" }, { "title": "ID import fee", "value": "currencydefinition.idimportfees" }, { "title": "Converter Name", "value": "currencydefinition.gatewayconvertername" }, { "title": "Proof Protocol", "value": "currencydefinition.proofprotocol" }, { "title": "Options", "value": "currencydefinition.options" } ]
```

Something like this happens as in the screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues I notice in your code:

1. You're using `expandedRow.value` inside the `toggleExpansion` method, but `expandedRow` is not defined. Instead, you should use `expanded`.
2. In the expanded row template, you're trying to access `headers.title`, which is incorrect. You should iterate over the `headers` array to display the titles.

   ```
   <template>
     <h1>Currencies</h1>
     <v-container variant="outlined" class="mx-auto pa-6 transition-swing overflow-x-auto">
       <v-data-table 
         :items="currencies" 
         :headers="headers" 
         item-value="title"
         v-model:expanded="expanded"
         show-expand
       >
         <!-- expanded card content -->
         <template v-slot:top>
           <v-toolbar flat>
             <v-toolbar-title>Expandable Table</v-toolbar-title>
           </v-toolbar>
         </template>

         <v-expand-transition>
           <template v-slot:expanded-row="{ item }">
             <tr>
               <td :colspan="headers.length">
                 More info about {{ item.currencydefinition.fullyqualifiedname }}
               </td>
             </tr>
           </template>
         </v-expand-transition>
       </v-data-table>
     </v-container>
   </template>

   <script setup>
   import { ref } from 'vue'
   import currencyHelpers from '../lib/currencyHelpers';

   const info = ref([]);
   const currencies = ref([]);
   const headers = [
     { text: 'Name', value: 'currencydefinition.fullyqualifiedname' },
     { text: 'ID', value: 'currencydefinition.currencyid' },
     { text: 'ID rego fee', value: 'currencydefinition.idregistrationfees' },
     { text: 'ID import fee', value: 'currencydefinition.idimportfees' },
     { text: 'Converter Name', value: 'currencydefinition.gatewayconvertername' },
     { text: 'Proof Protocol', value: 'currencydefinition.proofprotocol' },
     { text: 'Options', value: 'currencydefinition.options' }
   ];
   const expanded = ref([]);

   (async () => {
     info.value = await currencyHelpers.getInfo();
     currencies.value = await currencyHelpers.listCurrencies();
   })();

   </script>
   ```

Comment: Works fine now but all the rows expand together

Comment: I Edited my post you can do something like that for one row expanded at a time

Comment: I have updated my question with the updated code, still does the same

Comment: you should define expanded like this: `const expanded = ref(null);`

Comment: still the same expands all

Comment: What I learned from the docs is that you just add `item-value` to your `v-data-table` and it works, and you don't need `@click:row` to `expand` . I edited my post. And I tried this it works.

Comment: Still the same for some reason mate

Comment: So it may be for your `info` and `currencies` data, please give me their results and I will make a `codepen` for you.

Comment: Console results?

Comment: No, data results of `currencyHelpers.getInfo()` and `currencyHelpers.listCurrencies()`

Comment: i made a simple `codepen` for you but if you want you can get me your data and i make another one, [codepen link](https://codepen.io/Mohesn-Mahmoudi/pen/LYvGjpy)

Comment: The data is coming from a TS RPC library we are using that is fine, I have updated my code however, with a json response pasted as well